# socialengine integration with external php website

Tags: php, integration, socialengine

I am using social-engine as Social-networking website and at same time we are having another website done in php CodeIngiter MVC. Now we want to integrate Social-engine with our website. We are using Social-engine DB only for our php website.

When we log into our website it should be automatically logged into Social-engine also. I don't know where to start from? Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create custom login action (default login action is in application/modules/User/controllers/AuthController.php) and launch it using AJAX, but this way is not too good because you might get unpredictable problems with session or something else.
Better way is to create login action which will be launched by user. User will click button (like facebook or twitter login buttons) and launch custom login action using data from your php website, where he is already logged in.

Comment: asking user to click button like fb is not going to work for me, they have to be automatically redirected. I am passing through cURL and i am able to login into Social Engine home page also. but that session is saved only for that home page, when i click on other pages like events or groups, its taking me back to login section. Any idea how to get rid of these? Or what type of custom changes i can make to my login Action in AuthoController.php. How can i save session to work through out website when the request is coming from cURL?

Comment: @HemaChandra I don't sure I understood you. How exactly you're doing the request from cURL to login into SocialEngine?

Here is minimal requirements in order to login the user:
1) Logins are registered in user_logins table;
2) After that onUserLoginBefore hook is running;
3) $_SESSION['login_id'] must be also set;
4) After that onUserLoginAfter hook is running;

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create some API for the socialengine login and also in your php website. That way , it shall help you.

For, our mobile native application for one client, We used that approach and its working fine.